# How to create an object of a class, who has a private constructor

Tags: c++, oop

I have been given an assignment to create classes, but the constructors should be private. Now we have to store the lists using linked lists, but I am having trouble with declaring my objects of the classes I created.

```
 class Faculty
{
private :
    // Personal Information
    string Name;
    string DateOfBirth;
    string Address;
    int Phone;

    // Academic Information
    string Experience;
    string Department;
    string *coursesTeaching;
    string *coursesCanTeach;
    string areaOfInterest;

    // Managerial information
    float salary;
    string DateOfJoining;
    string Room;
    string ParkingLot;

    Faculty ();
    Faculty (string, string, string, int, string, string, string, float, string,
             string, string);

 public :

    //copy constructor
    Faculty (const Faculty &F);

    //static function for making objects
    static Faculty* create_faculty (string, string, string, int, string,
                                string, string, float, string, string, string);

    // setters
    void setName(string);
    void setDateOfBirth (string);
    void setAddress(string);
    void setPhone(int);
```

here is the CPP file definition of my static object creating function.

```
 //static function for making objects
 Faculty* Faculty :: create_faculty (string n, string d, string a, int p,
                                     string e, string dp, string ar, float s, 
                                     string doj, string r, string pl)
{
    Faculty* F1 = new Faculty(n, d, a, p, e, dp, ar, s, doj, r, pl);
    return F1;
}
```

and here is the main.

```
#include "AcademicStaff.h"
#include "faculty.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct FacultySt
{
    Faculty *f; 
    f = Faculty :: create_faculty (string n, string d, string a, int p, string e,
                                        string dp, string ar, float s, string doj,
                                        string r, string pl);

      FacultySt* next;
};
```

how can I create my object of Faculty class? The way I am doing it, its not working.

Comment: You've forgotten to ask the question.

Comment: Where's the `main` really? Is the assignment in `FacultySt`'s definition valid C++ syntax?

Comment: my object is not being created the way I am doing it. I will edit my question.

Comment: that is the problem, its not. I need a valid way to declare my object in there.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem. Most of your code is completely irrelevant. But the problem is that you cannot have an assignment outside of a function.

Comment: I am getting the errors

Comment: The only errors I am getting is in my main.
in FacultySt, where I am told that "f data member initializer is not allowed"

and "f declaration has no class type or specifier"

Comment: Exactly. You cannot say `f = blah` outside of a function. And that has **absolutely nothing** to do with private constructors.

Comment: then how am I suppose to call the create_class function?

Comment: alright I got it, I was making one of the silliest mistakes a programming student can ever make.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   Faculty *f;      //1
   f =/*anything*/; //2
   ```

   I don't think second line I quote is legal. It should be done in constructor.
   Alternatively, since C++11 you can write

   ```
   Faculty *f=/*something*/;
   ```
2. What the hell is that? :

   ```
   Faculty :: create_faculty (string n, string d, string a, int p, string e,
                                   string dp, string ar, float s, string doj,
                                   string r, string pl);
   ```

   It isn't valid function invocation, you should pass arguments, not... variables' declarations (?), or whatever it is.
3. Don't make functions taking `std::string`, instead take `const std::string&` - copying `std::string` may be expensive.
4. You don't need function `Faculty::create_faculty`, you can write

   ```
   Faculty *f=new Faculty(/*here the arguments*/);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A simple working example of what I think you are trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

class X {
public:
  static X* factoryMethod(int v) {
    return new X(v); }
  int get() {
    return n; }
private:
  X(int v) : n(v) {};
  int n; };

int main(int, char* []) {
  X* x = X::factoryMethod(5);
  std::cout << x->get() << std::endl;
  delete x;
  return 0; }
```